# Change button colors dynamically using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have two buttons which are in green and red color. I want to change color of button. Suppose If i click on red colored button green colored button to change to gray. Similarly when i click on green colored button  , red colored button to change gray. How i can achieve in angular js?

Comment: what you have tried so far???

Comment: You are looking for ng-class learn and then proceed https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: I am not sure what concept to use. Just started learning angular js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check working example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/DHQr4AMhBkQsgG4GwrB4?p=preview

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.click = '';
});
```

HTML

```
<button ng-click="click = 'red'" ng-class="{'red': click == 'red' || click == '', 'grey': click == 'green'}"> RED</button>
<button  ng-click="click = 'green'" ng-class="{'green': click == 'green' || click == '', 'grey': click == 'red'}">GREEN</button>
```

CSS

```
.grey {
  background-color :#808080;
}

.red {
  background-color :#FF0000;
}
.green {
  background-color :#008000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my 3rd day of reading angular js. This example will help me lot.